# Searching and coding using a list in R

Tags: string, r, list, dataframe

I have a 'list' of 'vectors' of strings and a 'data.frame' of strings as follows

```
lst <- list( c("key", "parking", "velvet"), c("sumatra", "cap"), c("sled", "card"), c("notice", "piece", "page"))

df <-  c("key", "sumatra", "band", "cattle", "camp", "sled", "page", "wire", "key", "card", "cap", "page")
df <- data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I would like to add column to dataframe `df` with codes based on membership in vectors in list `lst`. The desired output is like this.

```
df$code <- c("G1", "G2", "", "", "", "G3", "G4", "", "G1", "G3", "G2", "G4")

 df
        df code
1      key   G1
2  sumatra   G2
3     band     
4   cattle     
5     camp     
6     sled   G3
7     page   G4
8     wire     
9      key   G1
10    card   G3
11     cap   G2
12    page   G4
```

How can I do this in `R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
names(lst) <- paste0('G', seq_along(lst))
transform(df, code=with(stack(lst), ind[match(df, values)]))
#         df code
# 1      key   G1
# 2  sumatra   G2
# 3     band <NA>
# 4   cattle <NA>
# 5     camp <NA>
# 6     sled   G3
# 7     page   G4
# 8     wire <NA>
# 9      key   G1
# 10    card   G3
# 11     cap   G2
# 12    page   G4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df$code <- paste0("G",cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(sequence(sapply(lst,length)))<0)))[match(df$df, unlist(lst))]
df$code[is.na(df$code)] <- ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using the [qdapTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdapTools/index.html) package:

```
library(qdapTools)
names(lst) <- paste0("G", 1:length(lst))
df$code <- df[, 1] %l% lst
```

Answer (score 1):

And one more for good measure...

```
lst <- list(c("key", "parking", "velvet"), c("sumatra", "cap"), 
            c("sled", "card"), c("notice", "piece", "page"))
d <- c("key", "sumatra", "band", "cattle", "camp", 
        "sled", "page", "wire", "key", "card", "cap", "page")
DF <- data.frame(d, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

```
> l <- rep(seq_along(lst), sapply(lst, length))
> m <- l[match(d, unlist(lst))]
> DF$code <- ifelse(is.na(m), "", paste0("G", m))
> DF
##         df code
## 1      key   G1
## 2  sumatra   G2
## 3     band     
## 4   cattle     
## 5     camp     
## 6     sled   G3
## 7     page   G4
## 8     wire     
## 9      key   G1
## 10    card   G3
## 11     cap   G2
## 12    page   G4
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you start with the codes like this:

```
 MyCode <- c("G1", "G2","G3", "G4", "G1", "G3", "G2", "G4")
```

but you need to know what rows to put them in.  Try this:

```
df$code<-NA
df[df$df %in% unlist(lst),]$code<-MyCode
```

The `unlist()` part will turn your lists into a vector. The `%in%` part will return any row where `df$df` matches something in `lst`. Where there is no match, there will be a `NA` under `df$code`.